# How to run two batch scripts simultaneously?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I make a movie this summer, and to make the job easier, instead of doing special effects, I build a batch program.
When I run the first file (1.bat) it runs and in turn launches another (2.bat) (which displays a loading bar) and another (3.bat) (which displays a text list )
The problem is that the window where the text appears opens well, but the text does not scroll, yet when it is run all by itself it works.

Thank you in advance for your help

This is the code :

### 1.bat

```
@echo off
title [Launch Program]
cls
:var1
set /A k=%k%+1
if %k%==70 cls & echo Démarge en cours.
if %k%==140 cls & echo Démarge en cours..
if %k%==210 cls & echo Démarge en cours...
if %k%==280 cls & echo Démarge en cours.
if %k%==350 cls & echo Démarge en cours..
if %k%==420 cls & echo Démarge en cours...
if %k%==490 cls & echo Démarge en cours.
if %k%==560 cls & echo Démarge en cours..
if %k%==630 cls & echo Démarge en cours...
if %k%==700 cls & echo Démarge en cours.
if %k%==770 cls & echo Démarge en cours..
if %k%==840 cls & echo Démarge en cours...
if %k%==910 cls & echo Démarge en cours.
if %k%==980 cls & echo Démarge en cours..
if %k%==1050 cls & echo Démarge en cours...
if %k%==1120 start 2.bat
GOTO var1
```

### 2.bat (loading bar)

```
echo off
start 3.bat
color a
mode 103,5
set counter=0
set counterb=000
set core=±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±
set "valuecore=                                                                                                               "
setLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
:start
cls
echo.ÚÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄ¿
echo.³%valuecore:~0,100%³
echo.ÀÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÙ
if %counter% GEQ 100 set msg=complete& set counterb=10000& goto exit
echo.                        %counterb:~0,-2%%%
set /a counter=counter+1
set /a counterb=counterb+100
set "valuecore=!core:~0,%counter%!                                                                                                    "
set delay=0
:delay
if %delay%==125 goto start
set /a delay=delay+1
goto delay
:exit
echo. %counterb:~0,-2%%% %msg%
ENDLOCAL
exit
```

### 3.bat

```
@echo off
cls
title [Chargement des modules]
:var1
set /A k=%k%+1
if %k%==20 echo     Application........................0x9se5785
if %k%==40 echo     Application........................0x9865785
if %k%==60 echo     Application........................0x986hfgf
if %k%==80 echo     Application........................0x91gf4gd
if %k%==100 echo    Application........................0xa865785
if %k%==120 echo    Application........................0x9800785
if %k%==140 echo    Application........................0xk865gj7
if %k%==160 echo    Application........................0x7865hgf
if %k%==180 echo    Application........................0x9865785
if %k%==200 echo    Application........................0xROZ5ng8
if %k%==220 echo    Application........................0x986fgj7
if %k%==240 echo    Application........................0x9865gnf
if %k%==260 echo    Application........................0x9865785
if %k%==280 echo    Application........................0x98KE785
if %k%==300 echo    Application........................0x110cdf0
GOTO var1
```

Comment: did you try `3.bat` directly? Then `k` probably has a value, that it shouldn't have (i.e. greater than 300). Add a `set "k="` to the beginning of `3.bat`. You also should implement a way to exit the endless loop (like `if %k% lss 301 goto :var1`).

Answer (score 0):

Stephan, you are a genius !!

Actually, the `k` varriable takes it values to the `1.bat` so in the `3.bat` I have `set /A k=0` And it works

Thanks !